# Understanding a multi-line d3 chart example

Tags: d3.js

For example - The below link is a multi-line chart displaying 3 indicators (New York, San Francisco, Austin)

**http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3884955**

If I wanted to put a 4th indicator on top of Austin (a moving average) where in the code structure (what area so not to cause error) would I put the equation?

And how would I go about displaying the 4th line as **it is not conventional to the behavior of the other indicators** as they are drawn via d3.tsv("data.tsv", and data.forEach

I ask a question like this because I keep playing with these things but end up breaking them I can't seem to quite get-my-foot-in-the-door with the docs yet reading isn't totally helping I think because this is more visual than the javascript I am used to and it is a pity that there are few-zero notes at all in the example.

Comment: You should be able to calculate a moving average across the temperatures in the first forEach loop using an if statement.  You'd obviously have to add a key value pair to store this. You should then be able to get the keys from the revised data and use map function that is already in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/IWyOZU4tFAx5HFKCrjtQ?p=preview) for this interesting question. (Average in red.)

```
...
d3.tsv("data.tsv", function(error, data) {
    data.forEach(function(d) {
        d.date = parseDate(d.date);
        d.AVERAGE = (+d["New York"] + +d["San Francisco"] + +d["Austin"]) / 3;
    });
...
```

Comment: very very cool! How does d3 not put three lines on top of each other, as it is in a for each surely this happens three times so also 2/3 time would be a waist of computing power?

Comment: Hi, thanks. The data values for each indicator at the different data points are indeed different (including the added average), and so they fall at different points/heights in the y-scale. Am I misreading your question?